# Which is more suitable/correct usage: "forget your password?" or "forgot your password?"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, syntactic-analysis

As a web developer, this is a question that has bugged me for some time: when providing a way for users to reset their password, which link wording is more suitable or is the "proper" use?

- "**Forget** your password?" (as in, "Did you forget your password?")
- "**Forgot** your password?" (as in, "Have you forgot(ten) your password?")

There is a nicely related post here ([Is it correct to use 'Forgot password' or 'Forgotten password'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/670/is-it-correct-to-use-forgot-password-or-forgotten-password/751#751)), but that addresses "forgot" vs. "forgotten."

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Why not surprise everybody and use a complete sentence? _Forget your password?_ is short for _Did you forget your password?_ and _Forgot your password_ is short for _You forgot your password, you idiot?_. They're both grammatical, but the second one feels strange coming from software.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree with your main point (i.e. "sentences are awesome"), but I think that "Forgot your password?" is actually meant to be a shortened (and ungrammatical) version of "Have you forgotten your password?"

Comment: Right, but shortening is a characteristic of intimate speech and we're talking about a label on a computer screen here. That's pretty damned intimate for an uppity program; feels like those bulk emails that make sure to use your name in the first line. Complete sentences are at least a proxy for intelligent behavior, and that's what users would prefer in an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're set on keeping the sentence fragment, and do not want to use a complete sentence as @John Lawler mentioned in his comment for brevity or what have you, I'd go with forgot. It reads as more inquisitive ("Forget your password" regardless of punctuation feels like a command) and has the expected past-tense.