# "if you forget your password", "if you forgot your password" or "if you have forgotten your password"?

Tags: tenses

For a user manual, which one is the most suitable of the three tenses? The user hasn't forgotten his/her password when he/she is reading the manual.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to use 'Forgot password' or 'Forgotten password'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/670/is-it-correct-to-use-forgot-password-or-forgotten-password)

Comment: I could see any of these tenses (present, past simple, past perfect) being used. What is the pattern of the rest of the user manual? Without a context, I'd tend toward the past perfect (*If you have forgotten*) as it would indicate that the user had forgotten at a given point of time.

Comment: If it's true that "*the user **hasn't** forgotten*," then the second and third options are logically impossible. Is this really just a logic puzzle? Because assuming the statement you made is true, only the first option is possible. (Which talks about the situation in general, and is the only one that can apply to the future.) Or did you misrepresent what you were asking by saying that?

Comment: Most users don't read a manual from the start to the end like a novel. Most of them - if they ever read it at all - will only read the parts that are relevant to what they need to do at that time; if they're reading the section on forgotten passwords, they've *probably* forgotten their password at that point, and want to know what to do.

Comment: If you're focusing on the situation where forgetting a password is just a possibility that you're covering in the manual, you could write "If you should forget your password..." or "Should you forget your..."

Comment: One has to imagine that the manual comes in an envelope marked 'On no account read this manual if you've forgotten your password.'  Perhaps it should go on 'And do not read it if you cannot read.' Manuals (and their writers) can only address contingencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish for the largest number of readers to understand your message, use the present tense unless it is incorrect. It is not incorrect to use the present tense when describing a procedure:

**"If you forget your password, do the following:"**

You could probably use the present tense for the entire manual unless you must refer to actual past events or expected future events. This applies to all technical literature.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the confusion.

**To reset your password...**

Answer (score -1):

## If you have forgotten your password.

You would say:

> If you have forgotten your password.

Forgotten is the past participle of forget whereas forgot is the past tense of forget. When you say "have forgotten," you are talking in the present perfect tense.

Refer to [this website](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-forgot-and-forgotten) for more...